# how to display separate subcategory / subregion from main category / region in job manager plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am new on this forum site. I want filter out jobs according to state and city. But in job manager location plugin all location are in region list. So I want filter result accordingly sub region as city or anather dropdown for this.

```html
add_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', 'filter_by_state_field' );
function filter_by_state_field() {
    ?>
    <div class="search_categories">
        <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Select State', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
        
  <select class="job-manager-filter" name="filter_by_stste">
  <option value="maharashtra">maharashtra</option>
  <option value="Goa">Goa</option>
  <option value="Kerala">Kerala</option>
  <option value="Gujrat">Gujrat</option>
  </select>
    </div>
    <?php
}
 
 
add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings', 'filter_by_state_field_query_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_by_state_field_query_args( $query_args, $args ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['form_data'] ) ) {
        parse_str( $_POST['form_data'], $form_data );
         
        if ( ! empty( $form_data['filter_by_state'] ) ) {
            $state = sanitize_text_field( $form_data['filter_by_stste'] );
            $query_args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_job_state',
                'value'   =>  $state,
                'compare' => '=',
                'type'    => 'NUMERIC'
            );

            // This will show the 'reset' link
            add_filter( 'job_manager_get_listings_custom_filter', '__return_true' );
        }
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: What hav you tried so far ?

Comment: i have tried using custom field

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @Milap I have posted my code please see